# Verantwortung und Verantwortlichkeit

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Gibt es grundsätzlich einen Unterschied hinsichtlich des Sinnes zwischen Verantwortung und Verantwortlichkeit ?

Mir scheint, dass Verantwortung sich auf eine Schuld oder die Möglichkeit einer Schuld beziehen kann

> Seine Worte bezeugen seine Verantwortung.

(Die Verantwortung bezieht sich auf eine vergangene vollbrachte Tat.)

während Verantwortlichkeit immer das gesetzliche oder gerichtliche Gebiet der Zuständigkeit beschreibt.

> Die Firma übernimmt die Verantwortlichkeit für das Planvollziehen.

Stimmen Sie zu und könnten Sie weitere Beispiele ausführen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja...

"Verantwortlichkeit" meint üblicherweise die Verpflichtung oder Bereitschaft, Verantwortung für etwas zu übernehmen. Diese Verpflichtung kann rechtlich sein, aber sie kann auch in anderen Kontexten entstehen, wo Aufgabenbereiche zugeteilt werden wie in einer Firma oder im Verein. Es ist - wie Du sagst - ein eher rechtlicher Begriff.

"Verantwortung" meint die Verantwortung selbst, gerne auch in einem etwas breiteren Sinne. Es meint nicht notwendigerweise, dass man *verpflichtet* ist, diese auch zu übernehmen. Denoch wird es üblicherweise so benutzt, dass jemand diese für eine Tat oder Handlung und daraus erwachsene Konsequenzen übernimmt oder übernehmen will: Mach Dir keinen Kopf. Wenn es schief geht, übernehme ich die volle Verantwortung.

Im alltäglichen Gebrauch ist die Unterscheidung wie oben beschrieben nicht immer sehr klar und sie werden gelegentlich synonym verwendet, insbesondere wird aber 'Verantwortung' verwendet, wo man auch 'Verantwortlichkeit' verwenden könnte.

Vielleicht könnte man kurz sagen (mit den Worten von @phipsgabler): Verantwortlichkeit ist "normativ", Verantwortung "subjektiv", aber letzteres tendiert dazu, als allgemeines Abstraktum gebraucht zu werden.

Comment: Vielleicht könnte man kurz sagen: _Verantwortlichkeit_ ist "normativ", _Verantwortung_ "subjektiv", aber letzteres tendiert dazu, als allgemeines Abstraktum gebraucht zu werden.